# jQuery Datepicker set date onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I would like to confess, I don't understand jQuery, all what I have is that i found somewhere at the internet and somehow put together.

I have managed to make a function *date picker* that is triggered by a button click, after selecting a date the date picker will POST the date. Just like the date picker do.

What i want to do next is to make 2 more buttons today and tomorrow and onclick I want them to POST date of today and tomorrow in Y-m-d format...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('input').datepicker(
    {
//        maxDate :'+1m 10d',
//        minDate : '0',
//        closeText: 'Cerrar', 
//        prevText: 'Předchozí', 
//        nextText: 'Další',
//        currentText: 'Hoy',
//        monthNames: ['Leden', 'Únor', 'Březen', 'Duben', 'Květen', 'Červen', 'Červenec', 'Srpen', 'Září', 'Říjen', 'Listopad', 'Prosinec'],
//        monthNamesShort: ['Le', 'Ún', 'Bř', 'Du', 'Kv', 'Čn', 'Čc', 'Sr', 'Zá', 'Ří', 'Li', 'Pr'],
//        dayNames: ['Neděle', 'Pondělí', 'Úterý', 'Středa', 'Čtvrtek', 'Pátek', 'Sobota'],
//        dayNamesShort: ['Ne', 'Po', 'Út', 'St', 'Čt', 'Pá', 'So', ],
//        dayNamesMin: ['Ne', 'Po', 'Út', 'St', 'Čt', 'Pá', 'So'],
//        weekHeader: 'Sm',
//        firstDay: 1,
//        isRTL: false,
//        showMonthAfterYear: false,
//        yearSuffix: '',
//        dateFormat: 'yy-m-d',
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) 
        {
            $('#formId').submit();
        }
    });
    $('#kalendar').click(function () 
    {
        $('input').show().focus().hide();
    });
    $('#dnes').click(function()
    {
//        $('#datepicker').val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-m-d', new Date()));   
    });
    $("#zitra").click(function() 
    {
//        $( "#formID" ).submit();
    });
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $_POST["datum"]; ?>
 <form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='formId'>
  <input type="text" name="datum" style="display: none">
</form>   
</body>
<button id="kalendar">Calendar</button>
<button id="dnes">Today</button>
<button id="zitra">Tomorrow</button>
</html>
```

Most of the commented code is just localization. I've tried to complete it, but I didn't succeed... I think that it will be an easy task for most of people here, so that's why I turned here for help. Thanks! Atom

Comment: Call datepicker with input name selector. `$( "input[name*='datum']" ).datepicker`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below set the data selected for today and tomorrow buttons

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date(today.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
var $form = $('#formId');

    // set the default options 
    var DateOptions = {
        dateformat: "Y-m-d",
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $form.submit();
        }
    }
    $('input').datepicker(DateOptions);

    $('#kalendar').click(function () {
        $('input').show().focus().hide();
    });

    $('#dnes').click(function() {
    // update the date
        //$('input').datepicker('setDate', new Date(today)).hide();
        //Atom removed the use of the datepicker
        $('input').val(new Date(today));
        $form.submit();
     });
    $("#zitra").click(function() {
    // update the date
       //$('input').datepicker('setDate', new Date(tomorrow)).hide();
       //Atom removed the use of the datepicker
        $('input').val(new Date(tomorrow));
        $form.submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: ok thanks, that seam to work,  but it'll show the date picker when clicked on tomorrow and today's button... i would like the buttons only to set and POST the date without showing the date picker ...and ideally it would be the best to POST the date with format Y-m-d

Comment: Updated code above , that should update the datepicker without showing it

Comment: The last version doesn't seam to work..., the datepicker mostly apears (when clicked tommorow,today), the format is still the default and when clicked on the tomorrow and today's button, the form isn't sent... The value that i need to work with is the POST value, i would like to use it in PHP....


This is how i imagine it,[https://jsfiddle.net/fwbxLbtr /] but it doesn't submits the form and the output of the tommorow and todays button will be the default format...,

Comment: ok.. that is almost perfect!! Thanks! But there's only one tiny problem left, when clicked on tommorows or todays button the datepicker appears for split of a second...

Comment: try adding .hide() on the datepicker update $('input').datepicker('setDate', new Date(tomorrow)).hide();

Comment: yes.. i tried it and it still apears for split have this behavior

Comment: ok...i've managed to do it like this...[https://jsfiddle.net/fwbxLbtr/1/ ], the only think left is to format the output of the buttons, but i think it won't be that hard...

Comment: great to hear, that make sense as you are just updating the input value, so no need to use the datepicker. i will update the answer.

Comment: Jim? Can i ask you 1 more question? How do i make this datepicker apear into a specific div? Let's say that the div will have class="here".